# Java - Enhanced For Loop never ending

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach

This code is producing an endless loop:

```
        for (String element : friendSet) {
        resultNum ++;
        System.out.println("  Result # " + resultNum + " = " + element);
        System.out.print(" friendSet.size() = " + friendSet.size());
    }
```

friendSet.size() = 2923 but the results keep climbing to tens of thousands until I force the program to stop.  For example:

```
friendSet.size() = 2923  Result # 7652 = Charlie
friendSet.size() = 2923  Result # 7653 = Jamie
friendSet.size() = 2923  Result # 7654 = Smith
```

What is going on?

Comment: What is `friendSet`?

Comment: Let's guess: `friendSet` is your implementation of `Iterable` and the iterator your `#iterator()` method returns is broken.

Comment: Could you post code that will let us reproduce your problem on our computers? (there is high chance that while creating that code you will figure out problem yourself :)

Comment: what is initial value of resultNum

Comment: As a test, use the conventional `for` loop equivalent and it should behave the same way: `for (Iterator<String> i = friendSet.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    String element = i.next();
    . . .
}`

Comment: This is the code for the friendSet private static Set<String> friendSet = new HashSet<String>(6000);

Comment: Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: Why don't you make a set of three elements and see what gets printed. Anyway, create an SSCCE if you want a real answer.

Comment: Your example output doesn't match your code (result comes after size?). Please post the actual full code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes: foreach loops in java just use the objects `iterator`.

Is `friendSet` some kind of custom iterable collection? if so, your iterator implementation is not correct.

Comment: Unless it's Guava's Iterables.cycle() :-)

Comment: @FrankPavageau Jokes aside, I doubt `Iterables.cycle().size()` would return a definite number.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik As an Iterable, it doesn't have the size() method anyway. OP's friendSet is at least a Collection.

Comment: private static Set<String> friendSet = new HashSet<String>(6000);  This is the code.  It is just a normal set.

Comment: @Qwertyfshag Is your foreach loop inside of another loop?

Comment: @Colin Nope. This loop is on it's own

Answer (score 0):

The method that my for loop was in was being called more than once.  Thanks for the help guys.  Stupid error on my part.